# After update, my system is not working

Tags: updates

Just did an update on my 16.04 system. It's running on a Thinkpad t410. Suddenly, my system is nearly unusable - no menu applet, nothing at top of screen like wifi indicator or time, etc. Can I rollback my latest update? I updated from 14.04 way back in the Spring when 16.04 was first released.

Comment: I guess you have managed to login? can you right click and open in terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have managed to login and see your wallpaper and perhaps items in your desktop try right clicking a bare area and choose **Open in Terminal** from the context menu.

A window without decorations will emerge. Now enter the following:

```
cd
cd .cache
mv compizconfig-1 compizconfig-1-old
pkill -u $USER
```

The last command will kill your session and leave you back to the login screen. ALternatives to the pkill command are just going to a terminal pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> and the machine will reboot.

When you get a login screen just login and enjoy your unity menu and top bar with applets.

**Speculations on why this happens**

When looking at my /var/log/apt/term.log I noticed a lot of compiz packages being updated just before this happened. It only affects my user and never my wife so I guess it's because I do some customizations in preferences, and even ubuntu-tweak, while my wife doesn't.

Comment: @ChristopherNuzzi You're welcome. Consider [accepting the answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can run 16.04 with an older version of your kernel.

When you boot grub, the second menu option is **Advanced options for Ubuntu**. Open this sub-menu and you will be presented with the last working version of the kernel and possibly other kernel versions to try.

Hopefully one of them works and you can limp along with 16.04 to backup all your data and perhaps tweak the newest kernel installed with 16.04.

After you are up and running (or if), you can research your exact problems and see if a newer kernel fixes them. Ubuntu 16.04 ships with Kernel version 4.4 but some have had to upgrade to 4.7.3 (like yours truly).

You should `Edit` your question and put in the version you upgraded from, ie 14.04 or 15.04, etc. Then explicit instructions can be given for reinstalling that version if necessary (hopefully it won't be).

Comment: If he gets to login and see his desktop withou unity menu and top menu and applets what makes you think this is a kernel issue? Granted I saw it wanted me to reboot since linux-lsb had changed but so was all the compiz packages. I have the same issue on my user while my wife, who hasn't done any changes in her desktop, doesn't have eny problems and has her menu.

Comment: @Sylwester There have been lots of problems reported with Kernels since Ubuntu 14.04 which could be Kernel 3.13 or so but definitely <4.4. I used the word "hopefully" and "if" because we haven't ascertained the exact problems yet.

Comment: I tried rebooting and I had only one older kernel, 4.4.0-34, and it didn't work. I'm writing from the foobar user account right since I can open terminal and from that firefox but I cannot move the windows or switch and I still don't have any unity bar or top menu line. The last update updated a lot of compiz packages so I belive perhaps user config reset of some kind might help.

Comment: I got mine working. I'll make an answer on what I did.

Comment: @Sylwester can you please mention me in a comment when you do so that I get a notification. I"m interested in the solution.

Comment: @Ejaz I posted one now.

Comment: @Sylwester I just rebooted and Kernel version 3.13.0-92 is still there from when Ubuntu 14.04.1 was installed. All the other 3.13.xx kernel versions were deleted by the upgrade to 16.04 though. The upgrade process leaves the old kernel version as a psuedo-"roll back" which I just selected to run and double-confirm. It may be compiz as you fixed for yourself but his Thinkpad may be different than your platform with a host of different problems. I do hope your solution works for the OP though.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix You probably used 3.13.0-92 when you upgraded and have not done a `apt autoremove` since you upgraded then. I have been using 16.4 a month and this is a new issue for me. I do have other problems with this release though. Itlags when we user switch and xorg isn't as stable. Really irritating since this is supposed to be a stable LTS.1 release.

Comment: @Sylvester I like to keep lots of kernel versions around, it makes for a long menu in grub but I like to test under different versions. Running 3.13.0-92 now I notice how in flash player full screen in chrome 10 to 20 pixels are missing on top, left, bottom and right meaning controls have to be clicked by navigating mouse a bit off screen. This was fixed in kernel 4.4 when I installed Ubuntu 16.04. Which is why older kernel might give back stability to Ejaz.